# Memory leak on JavaScript with repeated page refreshes

Tags: jquery, html, memory-leaks

I am writing a webpage that will display statistics for a MySQL database that is maintained independent of the website. The idea is to have in constanly polling the MySQL DB and keeping the website up to date without having to reload it. I have a php page that does all of the database polling and logic on how or what to display. The main page the user accesses has a function that reloads the php page at a constant interval thereby automatically refreshing the polling on screen.

After I wrote everything it would work great for a while then it would crash without fail after a few hours regardless the browser I used. In chrome I brought up the Task Manager and noticed that the memory increased a lot in a short period of time. It would take a little under an hour to go from 10 mb to over 1 g. My initial thought was there was a large memory leak in the php script possibly from polling the MySQL database that often. To ensure it was that I commented out everything in the php script yet the leak still persisted. It has to be in the html and jQuery code I wrote. Javascript is not my forte, I am a novice to say the least. But I do know it has garbage collecting and so I thought my poor implementation is somehow preventing it from GCing.Can anyone see what may be causing this? The index.html is below. Like I said, index.php is blank now so I can't see what that would have any effect.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <title>"Statistics</title>
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=-1, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1">
    <script src="./js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#refreshpage").load("index.php");
            var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
                $("#refreshpage").load('index.php');
                }, 5000);
            refreshId = null;
            $("#refreshpage").unload();
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        });
        </script>
        <body class=bground>
            <center>
                <div id="refreshpage"></div>
            </center>
            <img id="logoShift" src="logo.png"/>
        </body>
</head>
```

Comment: If `index.php` is truly empty (returns no content), then the above code will not cause a memory leak. That, and it's pretty bad HTML, (e.g. `head` encapsulated `body`, 2 jquery libraries)  but I'm betting that was probably just some overzealous editing on your part to create a test case.

Comment: I think the most likely possibility is that `index.php` probably also had a timer in it and when you use `$.load` to populate a div, it loads everything from that page, and executes whatever Javascript is on that page. If `index.php` contained a timer like the above code, then every 5 seconds, not only would you be reloading `index.php`, you'd be setting up a new timer that reloads `index.php` and so on and so on until you had thousands of timers (memory leak).

Comment: It looks like it is the php script. After making adjustments to the html and jQuery(unloading the object, disabling the cache, etc...) I had to actually close down the browser for it to take effect. The problem reside in the php code. I don't have any timers in there but I am now re organizing, closing every connection to MySQL, dereferencing every objecting and setting every variable to Null just to be sure.

Comment: Server side objects in the PHP wouldn't cause the browser memory to increase. Depending on what scripts are in `index.php` when you load it, it's quite likely that they would also cause a memory leak. Rather than loading an entire page with `.load(index.php)` you should just be loading the precise HTML/JSON that you want.